# Android Grid View onItemClick not working

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have a grid view when user presses a button  i am changing grid view data and setting adapter again now on item click is not working but Touch listener is working WHY ?
I have two types of adapters when user presses button a i am setting first adapter when user presses button b i am setting second adapter data is changing but on item click  not working?

Comment: would u post  your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Because this kind of updates is always a problem, you have to do your adapter's update in onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute.

So, when your button is pressed, you execute your AsyncTask.

Comment: its working now i have used button in grid view element so when clickable items are present in gridview item it wont be clickable

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but maybe somebody else will seek for answers...

Anyway, I had a same issue and wasn't able to figure out why my `onItemClick()` didn't work. Instead of implementing `onItemClick()` inside your adapter, try doing it with `adapter.setOnItemClickListener()`. It worked for me ;)